# Accessing session token from other routers in node js

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am trying to access my session token from other routes after setting it in a route. I am currently unsuccessful. Following the relevant code of the three files.

`server.js`: It calls the routes thermostats, login and also sets session token.

```
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat',cookie: { secure: true }}))

var router = express.Router();
var thermostats = require('./api/routes/thermostats')(router, app, session);
require('./api/routes/login')(router, app, session, thermostats);
```

`login.js`: When the user goes to `localhost:3000/login/`, the login token needs to be saved in the session

```
module.exports = function(router,app, session, thermostats){
    router.get('/login/', function(req, res) {
        list(req, res)        //response of this function has session which needs to be saved. 

        console.log(res.session)

        app.use(session(res.session))   //trying to save the res.session as session token 
    });

}
```

`thermostat.js`: Needs to access the session token before can display any information.

```
module.exports = function(router,app){
    router.get('/thermostats/', function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.session) //Set to default/null values and not the updated session values
    });

}
```

It might be something small but I cannot figure out the issue. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Express-session should automatically save the session, based on the configuration.

Looking at the 'resave' config option in the express-session [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave):

> **resave**
>
> Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the session was never modified during the request. Depending
> on your store this may be necessary, but it can also create race
> conditions where a client makes two parallel requests to your server
> and changes made to the session in one request may get overwritten
> when the other request ends, even if it made no changes (this behavior
> also depends on what store you're using).

This is by default, true, so it should already start working without you needing to add `app.use(session(res.session)`.

Edit: You will be able to save to the session by adding fields to the `req.session` object:

```
router.get('/login/', function(req, res) { 
  getDataFromExternalApi(req, function(err, apiResponse) {
    var data = apiResponse.data;
    req.session.data = data;
    // if resave option is true, this should automatically save to the session store after this request is done.
  });
});
```

Generally, you shouldn't be using `app.use` in your request handlers. Those are generally reserved for setting up the server, as it defines what middleware express uses.

Comment: How will it automatically save the session? I want it to save `res.session` (returns from external API) in the function `list`. When I am accessing the values from /thermostats/ and viewing the `req.session`, it seems empty.

Comment: Ah I guess I misunderstood the situation. You have a session in an external API (which is called by `list`)  that you want to save in this current node session? If this is correct, then that is not possible. You need to expose the session data as part of the external API response in order for you to be able to save it in the current node session.

Comment: No, I think I didn't explain properly. The external API decides the session token but I want to save it in the current session on my application. It just tells me what the value should be and I need to save that.

Comment: You want to store the session token of the external API to the session of your current API?

Comment: Note: i've edited my answer to reflect what you said: you only need to add to the req.session object in order for express to automatically save your session.

Comment: Let me try this!